# EAV - Get value using Linq to entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-attribute-value

In a data model like this (http://alanstorm.com/2009/img/magento-book/eav.png) I want to get the value from an EAV_Attribute using Linq to SQL.

[image]

Assuming that an EAV_Attribute only exists in one inherited table (varchar, decimal, int, etc.) how can I get it in a linq query?

I know that I can use the Inheritance for this, but I want to execute it in the SQL Database side...

Is it possible to do a kind of Coalesce in Linq, considering that the elements have different types?

Comment: Assuming you're using C# to build your LINQ to SQL query, you can use the null coalesce operator (??) with outer joins.  Give it a shot!

Comment: I've already tried that, but I can't do it because "Value" property has a different data type in each table.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13673607

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework then you are using LINQ to Entities, not LINQ to SQL (a different technology that Microsoft declared end of life).

Comment: Also, what did you mean by "I know  that I can use inheritance for this" and why do you think that would prevent the query from being translated to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

EAV and linq is not a happy marriage. I think your best shot is to create an unmapped property in `eav_attribute` that resolves the value (as `object`) from it's typed attribute child. With entity framework, you won't be able to use this property in an expression (i.e. not in a `Where` or `Select`), You must convert to `IEnumerable` first to access it. (Linq-to-sql may allow it because it can switch to linq-to-objects below the hood).

Another option is to create a calculated column of type [`sql_variant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) that does the same, but now in t-sql code. But... EF does not suport `sql_variant`. You've got to use [some trickery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137509/Reading-sql_variant-in-Entity-Framework) to read it.

That's the reading part.

For setting/modifying/deleting values I don't see any shortcuts. You just have to handle the objects as any object graph with parents and children. In sql server you can't use cascaded delete because it can only be defined for one foreign key. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5018099/861716) may tackle that, but I never tried).

So, not really good news, I'm afraid. Maybe good to know that in one project I also work with a database that has an inevitable EAV part. We do it with EF too, but it's not without friction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend using TPH and not TPT for EAV tables. (One table with multiple nullable value columns (one per type) + discriminator vs. one table per type.)

Either way, if you modelled the value entity as an abstract class (containing the two IDs) with an inheriting entity per value data type that adds the value property, then your LINQ should look like this:

```
var valueEntity = context.ProductAttributes.Where(pa =>
        pa.ProductId == selectedProductId
        && pa.AttributeTypeId == selectedAttributeTypeId)
    .SingleOrDefault() as ProductAttributeOfDouble;

if valueEntity != null
    return valueEntity.Value;

return null;
```

Where the entity types are: Product, AttributeType, ProductAttribute, ProductAttributeOfDouble, ... ProductAttributeOfString.